# Multiple expanding buttons for WPF TreeView

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I've been reading questions and answers here for the past few years but this is my first question after not being able to find exactly what I need.

I'm creating a WPF MVVM Application.
In this application,I'm using a TreeView that Every Node in it is a Tuple of two objects(let's say strings for that matter).

I would like to add **Another** Expanding button, The original one from the left side of the node, and another one from the right side of the node.

I thought about adding a button to the TreeViewItem header, but I couldn't understand (after searches..) how to bind him to the expanding action.

Would love to hear some ideas...

Comment: If you add the button to the header template, you can then bind the button using an attached behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if we go take a look at the [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"` we see in there a `ToggleButton` as such;

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                        Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

So if say we wanted to (as per your requirement) duplicate that, in the same template we could do just exactly that but with a different name. Like;

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"
       TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
          Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
  <Setter Property="Padding"
          Value="1,0,0,0" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
          Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19"
                              Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <!-- ** Let's add a column for it ** -->
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                >
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
              <VisualState x:Name="SelectedInactive">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                        Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
          <Border x:Name="Bd"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
          </Border>
          <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          Visibility="Collapsed" />
          <!-- ** We add a duplicate ToggleButton to act as the expander ** -->
          <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander2" Grid.Column="3"
                        Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                   Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Hidden" />
          </Trigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="HasHeader"
                         Value="false" />
              <Condition Property="Width"
                         Value="Auto" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                    Property="MinWidth"
                    Value="75" />
          </MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="HasHeader"
                         Value="false" />
              <Condition Property="Height"
                         Value="Auto" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                    Property="MinHeight"
                    Value="19" />
          </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Main thing is just apply that `ExpandCollapseToggleStyle` to your ToggleButton, and make sure your `ClickMode="Press"` so you can hit it. You can either do this adhoc for your instance in a copied control template with a unique ID you apply, or to your default, whatever you prefer.

Hope this helps, and welcome to SO. Cheers :)

Comment: Hi, Chris
It works almost perfect so thank you so much for that.
problem is that it adds a lot of redundant arrows in weird places here is a printscreen [link](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10421426_10204038279343695_3421096564790375729_n.jpg?oh=9183ebccc95fcc33ab0c339455b966ed&oe=53983DD8&__gda__=1402457079_8a508c356a623d47e2bf9d78fb8288d)
and we wanted the second arrow to be just the one how is right next to the right object..

Comment: Sorry the link to your screenshot doesn't appear to be working. I didn't test this solution at all before posting but surely would be an easy fix in regards to the behavior you're referring to.